# How to use an abbreviated field name in MongoMapper

Tags: sinatra, mongomapper

I'm using MongoMapper and am trying to come up with a way to use an abbreviated field name.  I want to keep the keys as plain english but have the field names stored short (e.g. "name" maps to "_n").  I noticed a conversation but it ended up closed (https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/pull/351) and I was wondering if anybody has an example of how to accomplish this.  I'd be extremely grateful for any feedback!

Comment: I wasn't able to figure this out, switched to MongoID, and then eventually just wrote the code using the mongo library itself since it was much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Related to that conversation is another pull request, [#353](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/pull/353).  It hasn't been pulled yet but I'm guessing it likely will be, it simply may have been forgotten by the maintainers.

When pulled, your case will look like:

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :name, String, :abbr => :_n
end
```

I recommended leaving a comment on [#353](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/pull/353) saying that you were looking for that feature.